input() method catches all key press events before its execution
from pynput.keyboard import Events, Key, Listener

def on_release(key):
  if key == Key.enter: 
    return False

print("PRESS ENTER")

with Events() as events:
  for event in events:
    if type(event) is Events.Release and event.key == Key.enter:
      break

#  with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
#    listener.join()

input("First input: ")
input("Second input: ")

The code above it will "skip" the first input method because it will catch the enter key pressed in the with.
It catches every key you'll press, for instance: if I execute the script and type "hello" and press the enter key, this would be the result:
First input: hello
Second input: 

If I would press the enter key two times, the program would end execution because both input() would be skipped.
Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid this behaviour?
Thanks
Edit: Neither works with the listener, if you hold them both you are forced to press enter twice and the program terminates, without you being able to enter input into either function.
I'm executing the script in windows command line, while in vscode seems to work but not quite correctly.

Please extract and provide a [mcve], along with the produced output please. Also, how exactly do you run this program? On the commandline, it's likely that the event is emitted before you release the enter key there.

You seem to be blaming input, but the problem here (if it exists) would be in the keyboard module, for dispatching an event but not consuming it.  Which operating system and which keyboard module is this?  The keyboard module is highly system-specific.

input doesn't know anything about keyboard events. It only reads from standard input, which in this case is supplied your terminal.

I think the problem might lie in the fact that you press enter once in order to break out of the loop but this press is counted as an enter press for the input because the computer is precomputing something. Maybe adding a delay through time.sleep between loop and inputs could help

@UlrichEckhardt Sorry about that, I just edited my question. I'm using pynput and I'm executing the script in window command line. I hope it is clearer now

@Canbach Although I specified in the loop that it should be a release event, I had also thought about something like this and have already tried inserting delay between the loop and the inputs, but it still doesn't seem to work

pynput.keyboard.Events does not support suppressing keyboard events. Keyboard events that occur while an Events instance is listening will still be passed on to the rest of the system.
If you want to suppress keyboard events, you can use the pynput.keyboard.Listener class instead, and supply suppress=True:
with pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()

Note that pynput.keyboard is a module for handling the entire system's use of the keyboard, not just keyboard events that "should be" your code's responsibility. It will intercept all keyboard events, not just stuff you type into your application window.

Thanks for your reply, suppress=True can resolve the problem but it's quite overkilling, also because I have other key listeners in background that can't be catch if I put suppress=True, like symply the esc key to quit the program for example. pynput and keyboard module behave the same way. Is there a way to listening for keyboard events with these modules and then call the input method without all previously pressed keys being considered in the input()?
